# ResetPassword method in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net

The `ResetPassword` method is able to reset the old password, but user is unable to login with the new password generated by `ResetPassword` method. Code:

```
String user =(((TextBox)PasswordRecovery2.Controls[0].FindControl("UserName")).Text).ToString();
String newPassword = clsStatic.RandomString(10, false);
MembershipUser username = Membership.GetUser(user);
String resetPassword = username.ResetPassword();
username.ChangePassword(resetPassword, newPassword);
```

Comment: Maybe with all your testing you lockedout the user and didnt realize. Check if the user doesn't have the IsLockedOut bit set in the membership table.

Comment: sir i have already check for that,,for that checking purpose i am using an extra code  if (username.IsLockedOut == true)
            {
                username.UnlockUser();
            }
I have alredy check in database also,,,according to me each and everything is ok but still it is not login through a new generated password,,but thank you for ur help..and if u have code or a new logic then plz tell me...

Comment: dear jeroen i m waiting for your reply from a long time about my question,,do u have any idea that how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does ChangePassword return true or false?

I bet your random function returns a password that doesn't meet the criteria specified in your web.config membership section.

Since `ResetPassword` already gives you a new valid password why do you have to generate another one?

Comment: 1) I have tried this thing also just to use reset password method for both reset and generate a new password,but still it is not working.It will give a new password but when we try to login through a new generated password,then program does allow me...if u have a code then give it to me,,i m strucking from last 7 days in this problem,,,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your new random password generation should be ideally one of these

```
// this will automatically take care of all password criteria
string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 0);
```

Or

```
//for generating alpha numeric password only
string newPwd = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 11).Replace("-", "");
```

Your code is fine otherwise.

Comment: dear i have tried this thing also but still it does allow me to login through new generated password,,,,i have saved my password in hased form...

Comment: you are doing reset password cause your retrievepassword=false right? can you please paste your web.config membership provider so that we may see what sort of critieria are there for your password?

Comment: enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"              
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5000" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="100"
             applicationName="/" />

Comment: dear naveen,,no rply from ur side,,if u know that how to solve that problem then plz tell me..thanks..

Comment: i am clueless rahul. if you are getting an error, then we could solve it. I dont know currently what makes your reset non functional

Comment: dear i m also clueless,,my project does not show any error while working in reset password method,,it reset the old password very easily and also create a new one,but when we login through new password it is not login,i m also getting disturb,,,what thanks for your support....